# ExtJS - Bring to front created panel on Viewport

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm breaking my head.

Using the modern toolkit, I'm creating two panels directly in the viewport:

```
var clients = Ext.create('MyApp.view.clientsList', {fullscreen: true});
var providers = Ext.create('MyApp.view.providersList', {fullscreen: true});
```

How can I switch from one panel to other, because currently I can see only the last one created (providers)?

I tried with:

- clients.show(); // without success
- clients.bringToFront(); // error because isn't a floated panel

Maybe using z-index?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move clients and providers components to Ext.Carousel. Something like this:

```
var carousel = Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        clients,
        providers
    ]
});
```

[Fiddle sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/372a)